# Pattern for extracting paths where filename starts with 0/ 1 using pathlib glob

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I tried using normal python `regex patterns` in `pathlib glob` but it's not working.
While reading online I came to know that the glob patterns are quite different.
I did not found the pattern online which I was looking for.

**I have:**
a folder named **`images`** like:

```py
from pathlib import Path

print(list(Path('./images').glob("*")))
```

**gives:**

```py
[WindowsPath('images/01.jpg'),
 WindowsPath('images/11.jpg'),
 WindowsPath('images/010.jpg'),
... ]
```

I want glob to extract only those images whose name **starts with 0** like `01.jpg` & `010.jpg` & **not `11.jpg`**
What will be the pattern to achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pathlib's iterdir` and `startswith`

```
p = Path('./images')
for pth in p.iterdir():
    if pth.name.startswith('0'):
        print(pth)
```

---

```
images/01.jpg
images/010.jpg
```

Comment: The edited ans works! So that means we dont have specific pattern for this problem & need to use this approach....

Comment: Yes this only requires to get the name and check whether they start from 0 or not.

Comment: Hay! it turns out that my images folder also has some txt files how can I filter them out...

Comment: `if pth.name.startswith('0') and pth.name.endswith(".txt")` You have endswith also.